# C iterate over struct bad data

Tags: c, pointers, struct, sizeof, dynamic-memory-allocation

I add values to my structure in while loop.

```
struct person
{
    char * name;
    char * surname;
    int  age;
    char * email;
};
struct person * tablicaOsob[100];

//for loop
tablicaOsob[i] = createPerson(name, surename, age, email);
```

Data has been added correctly. I check this via debugger

[image]

Now I would like iterate over `tablicaOsob` I create function

```
void list_persons(struct person *p, int k)
{
    printf("Lista osob\n");

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", p[i].name );
    }

}
```

But when I fire this function: `list_persons(&tablicaOsob,i);` I gets some bad data. Where is the problem. And my compilator says:

```
main.c:74:17: warning: passing argument 1 of 'list_persons' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
                 list_persons(&tablicaOsob,i);
                 ^
main.c:17:6: note: expected 'struct person *' but argument is of type 'struct person * (*)[100]'
 void list_persons(struct person *p, int k)
```

EDIT:

`createPerson()`

```
struct person * createPerson(char * name, char * surename, int age, char * email)
{

    struct person * p = (struct person *) malloc(sizeof(struct person *));

    p->name = name;
    p->surname = surename;
    p->email = email;
    p->age = age;

    return p;

}
```

Comment: `list_persons(&tablicaOsob,i);` --> `list_persons(tablicaOsob,i);`

Comment: Its not working :(  I put breakpint in for in printf http://s32.postimg.org/6anjl56fp/brakpoint.jpg

Comment: Please how us `createPerson()`. I smell null-termination issue there...

Comment: Ok, I put this function in my question. But why output from debugger of `tablicaOsob` is ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the issue in in memory allocation. You're allocating way less memory to `p` than it needs. After that, accessing the returned pointer cause out of bounds memory access which in turn invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In your code,

```
  struct person * p = (struct person *) malloc(sizeof(struct person *));
```

you are allocating memory only for the size of a "pointer to object", not for the size of "object" itself. You should write

```
struct person * p = malloc(sizeof(struct person));
```

or, for better

```
struct person * p =  malloc(sizeof*p);
```

Also, while calling the function, you should pass a pointer to the structure, something like

```
 list_persons(tablicaOsob[0],i); //tablicaOsob[0]is of type struct person *
```

should do the job, as long as `i` value does not cause out of bound access.

That said, [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: I change fire function to `list_persons(*tablicaOsob,i);` and It works. I don't change memory allocation.

Comment: Ok, It's not ok. Function `list_persons` shows only last record.

Comment: @lukassz What do you mean only last record? You know the difference of using `=` between an `int` and a `char` array, right?

Comment: When I add 2 record in my for loop into struct, and when I fire `list_persons` function they show me only last record whose I put into struct.

Comment: @lukassz check the value if `i`, it maybe having a value that you don't expect it to have which can cause UB.

Comment: I check this, is correct. When I execute this for without function `list_presons` and `printf("%s", tablicaOsob[i]->name); it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Your `createPerson` function is totally wrong.

1. You are doing the initial malloc incorrectly, as mentioned by Alter Mann and Saurav.
2. You need to also allocate memory for the pointers `name`, `suname` and `email`. This is required for allocation of multiple persons over a loop. You need to allocate memory of `strlen(xxx) +1` for each character array.

The function will look like this:

```
struct person * createPerson(char * name, char * surename, int age, char * email)
{
  struct person * p = malloc(sizeof(struct person));

  p->name = malloc(strlen(name)+1);
  strcpy(p->name, name);

  p->surname = malloc(strlen(surename)+1);
  strcpy(p->surname, surename);

  p->email = malloc(strlen(email)+1);
  strcpy(p->email, email);

  p->age = age;

  return p;

}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for correct. Why I must add `+1` to `strlen`?

Comment: @lukassz  For a C String, the last character is `\0`. You need to make space for this character in your memory. e.g. if string is "abc", you store a,b,c,\0 in memory. (4 locations)

Comment: Ok. But why for loop in `list_person` display only first record of structure? When I put two record.

Comment: Call the function as `list_persons(*tablicaOsob,i)`

Comment: I call them. But *p in this function has only one element.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct person * p = (struct person *) malloc(sizeof(struct person *));
```

This is wrong, you want to reserve space for a `struct`, not for a pointer to this `struct`.

Change to

```
struct person *p = malloc(sizeof(struct person)); /* Don't cast malloc */
```

or

```
struct person *p = malloc(sizeof(*person));
```

This is also wrong:

```
list_persons(&tablicaOsob,i);
```

`list_persons` is expecting a pointer and `tablicaOsob` is an array of pointers, dont pass the address of an array of pointers to a single pointer, pass his value or simply pass the first element.

```
list_persons(*tablicaOsob,i);
```

Comment: I don't known... I change function to `list_persons(*tablicaOsob,i);` and it's works fine.

Comment: So I have one more question. Why is wrong in my memory allocation? I don't change this for yours and it works.

Comment: And can you explain me the point of * in `list_persons(*tablicaOsob,i)`?

Comment: Is wrong because `sizeof(struct person *)` returns the size of a pointer (4 or 8 bytes depending of the architecture) and you want the size of the `struct` itself.